# JFolder::create: Could not create directory Path: /var/www/html/t3-assets

Tags: joomla3.5

**Joomla! 3.6.5**
After install T3 template,a warning popup while I click T3 in template manager.

JFolder::create: Could not create directory Path: /var/www/html/t3-assets
I have tried to modify the $log_path and $tmp_path,but it doesn't work.

Comment: See http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/161/120

Answer (score 0):

After trying many methods,I finally found the problem..
It's access problem,
chmod 777 html
and reinstall the T3 template.
It's OK!

Comment: Changing file permissions to 777 is a short term solution at best and if left like this leaves your website vulnerable to hackers.